# How to disable a portion of JavaScript on a website

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, javascript, scrolling, ublock-origin

I'm trying to disable smooth scrolling. I tried a bunch of JavaScript in Tampermonkey. It worked on some sites, some don't and some disable scrolling altogether, which leads me to believe that there's something else at play.

Two websites here as examples:

example 1: www.Rwlabs.com
  example 2: www.ssiportable.com/custom-engineering/structural-modification/

In example 1, I pressed F12 to go into inspector mode for the scrollbar, and found that "nicescroll.min.js" is the JavaScript associated with scrolling (name suggested). I typed that line into my uBlock Origin extension and smooth scrolling is now disabled, but that does not work on link 2.

In the 2nd example, I'm doing same as in example 1. The JavaScript file is called *main.min.js*, but strangely enough nothing happens. It has to be /main.min.js in uBlock Origin for some reason, but it will disable the entire scrollbar altogether. When in inspector mode and clicking on the event for that JavaScript, it will show mousedown, mouseup, mozmousepixelscroll, etc. which I think are associated with smooth scrolling only.

How can I disable *only* the mousedown, mouseup or mozmousepixelscroll portion of that main.min.js JavaScript in the adblock extension, so I can disable smooth scrolling but not remove the scrollbar entirely?

Comment: May be there are some cdns which are conflicting with each other.